# How do I access a ruby array from my c extension?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I'm getting this error

```
ev.c:11: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

for this line

```
printf("%d\n", pairs[0][0]);
```

In this code

```
static VALUE EV;
static VALUE PairCounter;

static VALUE 
sort_pairs_2(VALUE self) {
    VALUE pairs;

    pairs = rb_ivar_get(self, rb_intern("pairs"));
    printf("%d\n", pairs[0][0]);
  return Qnil;
}

void Init_ev() {
    rb_eval_string("require './lib/ev/pair_counter'");
    VALUE PairCounter = rb_path2class("EV::PairCounter");
    rb_define_method(PairCounter, "sort_pairs_2", sort_pairs_2, 0);
}
```

Am I using self incorrectly, and rb_ivar_get is not actually pointing to the PairCounter class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to use the `RARRAY_PTR` macro on `pairs` to get at the underlying array; for example, the internal implementation of Array#push (for 1.9.2) looks like this:

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_push_1(VALUE ary, VALUE item)
{
    long idx = RARRAY_LEN(ary);

    if (idx >= ARY_CAPA(ary)) {
        ary_double_capa(ary, idx); 
    }
    RARRAY_PTR(ary)[idx] = item;
    ARY_SET_LEN(ary, idx + 1);   
    return ary;
}
```

The `if` just sorts out any necessary resizing, then there's `RARRAY_PTR(ary)[idx]` for accessing a single slot in the array.

I don't have any official references to back this up but hopefully this will be of some use.

Comment: Thanks mu, this code oriented me and got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby arrays are accessed with rb_ functions - not like normal C arrays.

Use `rb_ary_entry`

> `VALUE    rb_ary_entry(VALUE self, long index")`
>
> *Returns array `self`'s element at `index`.*

**Reference:**

http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html

See a list of common Array functions under *"Commonly Used Methods"*.